Issue referencing a second database/datasource in my application
I'm having issues incorporating a second database into my application.

I've created both connections in app.php and app_local.php
The model (ie. BusinessRequests) referencing the second database implements defaultConnectionName()

Error:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'app_a.business_requests' doesn't exist

Resulting SQL - note missing database/connection prefix when referencing BusinessRequests in the LEFT JOIN
SELECT
  Requests.id AS Requests__id,
  Requests.business_request_id AS Requests__business_request_id,
  Requests.notes AS Requests__notes,
  Requests.created AS Requests__created,
  Requests.modified AS Requests__modified,
  BusinessRequests.id AS BusinessRequests__id,
  BusinessRequests.title AS BusinessRequests__title,
  BusinessRequests.status AS BusinessRequests__status,
  BusinessRequests.created AS BusinessRequests__created,
  BusinessRequests.modified AS BusinessRequests__modified
FROM
  requests Requests
  LEFT JOIN business_requests BusinessRequests ON BusinessRequests.id = Requests.business_request_id
WHERE
  Requests.id = 1
LIMIT
  1

Database app_a (Note foreign key setup)
CREATE TABLE `requests` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `business_request_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_requests_app_common.business_requests` (`business_request_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_requests_app_common.business_requests` FOREIGN KEY (`business_request_id`) REFERENCES `app_common`.`business_requests` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

Database app_common
CREATE TABLE `business_requests` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=70270 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

Content of app.php
  'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => Connection::class,
        'driver' => Mysql::class,
        'persistent' => false,
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
    ],

    'common' => [
        'className' => Connection::class,
        'driver' => Mysql::class,
        'persistent' => false,
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
    ],
],

Content of app_local.php (mariadb is a Docker container)
'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [
            'host' => 'mariadb',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'database' => 'app_a',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
        ],

        'common' => [
            'host' => 'mariadb',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'root',
            'database' => 'app_common',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
        ],
    ],

Content of BusinessRequestsTable.php
Here I specify the connection to use for the model.
public static function defaultConnectionName(): string
{
    return 'common';
}

Content of RequestsController.php
public function view($id = null)
{
    $request = $this->Requests->get($id, [
           'contain' => ['BusinessRequests'],
    ]);

    $this->set(compact('request'));
}


You cannot join tables from different connections, if that's what you're trying to do. The query will be submitted to MariaDB server and processed there, server doesn't know anything about other connections the client might have established. Connections are independent; they don't even need to belong to the same server.

I just need to ensure read in the other database for the current default connection then?

Strange. If I keep $this->setTable(Configure::read('br_db_name').'.business_requests'); but remove common connection and defaultConnectionName() from the Model, it doesn't work: Table 'app_a.business_requests' doesn't exist

If both databases can be accessed through the same connection (i.e. same server + same credentials), that's the way to go. I can't tell you though if CakePHP/4 supports it (I last used the framework at an earlier version that didn't).

An old feature request. It wasn't implemented back then, but it contains good ideas.

In this case, setting the prefix of the database (ie. app_common), when setting the table in the model, seemed to resolved the issue.
public function initialize(array $config): void
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('app_common.business_requests');
    $this->setDisplayField('title');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
}


Please specify in the query which table to which database belongs. Try something like this:
SELECT
    Requests.id AS Requests__id,
    Requests.business_request_id AS Requests__business_request_id,
    Requests.notes AS Requests__notes,
    Requests.created AS Requests__created,
    Requests.modified AS Requests__modified,
    BusinessRequests.id AS BusinessRequests__id,
    BusinessRequests.title AS BusinessRequests__title,
    BusinessRequests.status AS BusinessRequests__status,
    BusinessRequests.created AS BusinessRequests__created,
    BusinessRequests.modified AS BusinessRequests__modified
FROM
    app_a.requests Requests
    LEFT JOIN app_common.business_requests BusinessRequests ON BusinessRequests.id = Requests.business_request_id
WHERE
    Requests.id = 1
LIMIT
    1


How would I configure the database prefix to be included in the query?  In the find? The model maybe?
